# What do the values of the C++ "feature test macros" mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-flags, dialect

To test for a feature, cppreference mentions these feature test macros:
[link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros).

If the feature is present in the compiler, the macro is defined. But I don't understand why, if defined, they are defined to something like `201606`, which I believe is **a version of C++, not of the compiler**.

For example, I am using a very recent version of GCC with `-std=c++17` for the feature `__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size`. The macro is undefined, which I take to mean GCC doesn't have the feature, despite trying 8.2.1 with the c++17 (and c++2a) switch. In this case, what is the significance of the documented value:

`__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size   201703`

(inside the cppreference link)?

Comment: It seems to me It's just future-proofing so that if a feature is deemed incomplete and in need of an update in future versions of the standard, a distinction can be made between pre and post update.

Comment: Also, FYI, it is a version of C++ (not a version of the compiler) because the features are part of the C++ standard, so any compiler compliant to version X of C++ will have those features. I.e. feature support is dependent on the C++ version, not the compiler version (sure, the compiler version tends to increase as it adds support, but the language version is the real key).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test), it says:

> The following macros expand to a numeric value corresponding to the
>   year and month when the feature has been included in the working
>   draft.
>
> When a feature changes significantly, the macro will be updated
>   accordingly.

So, you can check if the feature exists checking if the macro is defined. Or you can check for the feature version based on the macro value.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you that [feature_test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) is described as not in the best way. In these cases, it's better to use Languages Standards. They are not publicly available for free, but there are working drafts:

- [1] Draft of C++2017. Document Number: N4659 / Date: 2017-03-21 / Revises: N4640. [link](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)
- [2] Draft of C++2020. Document Number: N4861 / Date: 2020-04-01 /Revises: N4849. [link](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf)

(Links with draft can be out of date after 10 years, but I have provided the names of the documents to not violate StackOverflow policy.)

---

> For example, I am using a very recent version of GCC with -std=c++17 for the feature __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size. The macro is undefined, which I take to mean GCC doesn't have the feature...

Not exactly. Let's be careful. This inline constexpr constant is available from C++2017  [hardware_destructive_interference_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size), but the problem is that feature_test  [feature_test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) abilities with `__cpp_*` has been introduced only in C++2020. You will not find any of `__cpp_*` Marcoses in [1]. What is not supported is **not** a feature in C++2017 from GCC Toolchain, but the ability to test a feature with feature test macros by itself.

> To test for a feature, cppreference mentions these feature test macros...

You can test the feature if feature testing is supported. And it is supported only from C++2020 (officially).

In all versions of C/C++, the compiler reserved the following names:

- Starting with a double underscore `__`
- Names that start with a single underscore `_` followed by an uppercase letter.

You can try to use this mechanism in C++98/03/11/14/17, but the macro may be undefined, and in `#if` statement the undefined macro will be expanded as `0` value.

But it's very unreliable.

> They are defined as something like 201606, which I believe is a version of C++, not of the compiler...

Be careful. Section 15.11 [2] does not state that exactly. However, I hope toolchain implementation will define exactly what you said. Unfortunately, the (working draft of) standard does not force that.

---

Dear @J. Calleja

> So, you can check if the feature exists by checking if the macro is defined.

Yes, but if you use C++2020, not C++98/03/11/14/17.

> Or you can check for the feature version based on the macro value.

I'd like to add an extra comment. Please be aware of the following statement from [2], Section 15.11, p.455:

*"Future versions of this International Standard might replace the values of these macros with greater values."*

And I don't see anything which mentions this inside [cppreference feature_test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

If you want to produce compatible code use constructions like:

```cpp
#if __cpp_char8_t >= 201811L
///
#endif
```

Comment: *You cannot use this mechanism in C++98/03/11/14/17* - This is not true for libstdc++. If your standard library version is recent enough, it will define those macros. They are [not gated on the C++ standard version being set to 20 or greater](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/version) during the build.

Comment: @ComicSansMS. Ok, I will fix the text to "it's not reliable". Thank you very much.

Comment: https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf -  `__cpp` mentioned 0 times (A); In cpp reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) there is a mention that it is supported from C++20. There are several options (I) Bug in Cpp reference and bug in the working draft; (II) Bug in GCC; (III) GCC can do whatever they want and define what they want, but this guarantee nothing. In fact, Implementation can define any symbols starting with two underscores "__(.)*" or "_[A-Z]" starting from old C89.

Comment: The question is tagged `gcc`. There is no bug in the C++ standard, nor is there in libstdc++. Everything works as expected, your interpretation of the implications of this feature being introduced only in C++20 for the libstdc++ implementation is incorrect.

Comment: I see. Can you provide a reference from which I can learn that this is introduced earlier? Because by this link - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test "Feature testing (since C++20)"

Comment: @ComicSansMS I have provided two documents that support that this library feature appeared only in c++20, can you provide some material from your side? I am glad to learn, but you do not provide any source of information.

Comment: I did provide material in my first comment. Your answer is still suggesting that the fact that the question used `-std=c++17` is of significance here, which is misleading. The *only* thing the accepted answer does not mention that libstdc++ only started gradually introducing those macros starting with version 9.2, which addresses why the setup in the question has the macro as undefined. What you wrote, while technically correct, I feel is irrelevant in the context of this question which, at the core, is about the meaning of the number the macro would have had if it was defined.

Comment: You have provided a link to GCC source code and it's great. But the C++ Language is not defined by GCC (C++ compiler and C++ std. libraries) defined by C++ Standards.